# Multiple Inheritance on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how are you, people? I am facing this problem: I want to get all methods and attributes of 2 classes like the example below

```py
class Person1:
      def __init__(self) -> None:
          self.john_name = "John"
          self.john_age = 36
  
      def get_name_john(self) -> str:
          return self.john_name
  
      def get_age_john(self) -> int:
          return self.john_age
  
  
class Person2:
      def __init__(self) -> None:
          self.ted_name = "Ted"
          self.ted_age = 32
 
      def get_name_ted(self) -> str:
          return self.ted_name
 
      def get_age_ted(self) -> int:
          return self.ted_age
 

class Student(Person1, Person2):
      def __init__(self) -> None:
          super().__init__()
          print(self.john_age)
          print(self.ted_age)
          print(self.get_name_john())
          print(self.get_name_ted())
          print(self.get_age_john())
          print(self.get_age_ted())
 
 
student = Student()
```

But when I do this I can't access anything from Person2. Maybe someone can help me with it? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: If you want to use `super()` with multiple inheritance, then *every* class has to use it - even the base classes.  The alternative would be to explicitly call both parent class's `__init__` methods from `Student.__init__()`.

Comment: I didn't get yet. May you show an example, please?

Comment: Read the following: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `super().__init__()` to `Person1` and `Person2` as well. This is because of [Method Resolution Order (MRO)](http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html).

When `__init__()` is called in the `Student` class, the order at which to resolve `__init__()` is as follows:

```
Student -> Person1 -> Person2
```

Because `__init__()` is only called once, you would only be able to access `Person1` which is one down the hierarchy.

After adding `super().__init__()` to both `Person1` and `Person2`:

```py
class Person1:
      def __init__(self) -> None:
          self.john_name = "John"
          self.john_age = 36
          super().__init__()
  
      def get_name_john(self) -> str:
          return self.john_name
  
      def get_age_john(self) -> int:
          return self.john_age
  
  
class Person2:
      def __init__(self) -> None:
          self.ted_name = "Ted"
          self.ted_age = 32
          super().__init__()
 
      def get_name_ted(self) -> str:
          return self.ted_name
 
      def get_age_ted(self) -> int:
          return self.ted_age
 

class Student(Person1, Person2):
      def __init__(self) -> None:
          super().__init__()
          print(self.john_age)
          print(self.ted_age)
          print(self.get_name_john())
          print(self.get_name_ted())
          print(self.get_age_john())
          print(self.get_age_ted())
```

The code now works.

Comment: Got it! If i just want to share a specific method of the 2 classes, for instance, just calling john_age from first class and ted_age from the second, I can do it as well, right?

Comment: If you want to call a specific function from a parent class, you can just do `super().function_name()`. If that function exists in multiple parent classes, MRO will also apply, the same way it does here with `__init__()`. To change the order of MRO, you can simply change the order of the parent classes. For example you can swap the two classes around in `Student(Person1, Person2)`, so that it would become `Student(Person2, Person1)`, then the order of MRO would become `Student -> Person2 -> Person1`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for the answer. I marked your answer as the correct one.